# profiling with g++

Tags: g++, profile

How to profile c++ code to get the call times and cost time of each line of the code, just as the profile tool
in Matlab does?

I tried to use things like -fprofile-arcs, but it only generates a code coverage report, in which call times can be found, but cost time cannot.

Can anybody help out? Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compile with `g++ -pg` (or `-p` maybe or even `--coverage`; and `-Wall` is always helpful), then use `gprof` (or even `gcov`). And you could learn to use `oprofile`; read more about GCC [debugging options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)

Comment: I use `gprof` and `gcov`, as the OP said, these give you counters (number of time functions get called) but I do not see timers (how much real time did this function consume) and even less a list of such in descending order... http://lcov.csspp.org/csspp-1.0.10/lib/compiler.cpp.gcov.html